# Weight Paint mode makes my mesh white? Is it locked?

Tags: weight-painting

I'm having this issue with weight paint.

This particular mesh turns white and I can't paint over it. This happens whenever I access the weight paint mode, regardless of being unparented and parented back.

Unfortunately, I left my computer alone for a couple hours, when I came back it was like this. I was alone by then, so there was nobody else who could play with it.

Someone suggested me to check my overlays, yet I haven't had any luck yet.
I even tried loading Blender's factory settings, in hopes of fixing this.

How can I revert it back to normal? Or what is this "mode" even called? I can't work on it like this.

[image]

Comment: It might be useful if you [uploaded a simplified file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for other users to have a look at.

Comment: I have uploaded my file to my original post, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have enabled the *Paint Mask > Face Selection* option, which allows you to only paint on the selected faces, so either disable it or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> and left click to select the faces you want:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Damn, I feel like an idiot!
Thank you so much for being so helpful, man

Answer (score 0):

At first what moonboots said, and the reason you can't paint over the tie is related to the fact it's different objects your tie and suit.
And because they are not connected to each other they do not share any space together.

you can either join the tie to the suit, what would give you the ability to paint over the tie. but that would only make sense when you want to have the tie animate in a certain way when the suit is moving.

but when you want to have it act the cartoonish way, like rotating around or bend back and forth, then you have to have add a bone to it anyway.

But when you want to have it to move the same way the suit moves. You have it to be a child of your bones.
[Select] the tie, [ctrl + select] the bone and then [ctrl + P] to "Parent with auto weights" or whatever fits best for you.

That way the tie simply follows the same path as the suit does